# What happens when I modify the copy constructor to do something weird and then pass an object (of that class) by value to a function?

Tags: c++, pass-by-value

```
class C
{
public:
  C(C& c)
  {
    i = c.i;
    j = 100;
  }
  C() : i(0), j(0)
  {
  }

  int i, j;
};

C func(C c)
{
  return c;
}

int main()
{
  C c;
  c = func(c)
  // What is the value of j?
}
```

Above is a class with an unusual copy constructor. Instead of copying i and j, it copies i and assigns something else to j. What happens when I pass an object of the class to the function?

Edit: It just seems like such a tricky thing to do in a program...

Comment: Have you **tried** it and observed the result?

Comment: "try it" is really really bad advice.  The behavior depends on the optimizer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm inclined to disagree. I better question would be, "I wrote this code, but strangely this-and-this unexpected result happens. Why is that?" As it stands, there appears to be *zero* effort on part of the OP to even make a start.

Comment: @KerrekSB: but what if you try running the code, and get the boring, ecpected, result? Then you don't really have anything to ask about, and you might draw the wrong conclusion (that this behavior is requried, rather than something that *might* occur) -- and I haven't seen anything in the rule book specifying the amount of effort someone is required to put in before being *allowed* to ask a question here.

Comment: @jalf: still, any one of two questions that come to mind would be preferable: 1) "The value of the object is changed by my weird copy constructor; why isn't a 'real' copy enforced?", or 2) "The original value is copied; why isn't my weird copy constructor used?" I agree that certain abstract questions can be interesting in their own right, but for this case here I think it's poor form not to include any sort of "what have I tried" data.

Comment: Well, I disagree. :) and what's more, I think it's *really* poor form to discourage questions on purely subjective grounds. This site *needs* people asking questions. If there isn't a hard and fast rule for why you should do X before asking a question, don't push your opinion on others if they might discourage them from using (and benefiting) the site

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The copy constructor may be called, in which case your weird behavior happens.

Or, the compiler may elide the copy (this is specifically allowed by the standard), breaking your expectations.  In this particular case that isn't allowed, but in many contexts it is.

So don't write copy-constructors that do weird things.  (Or else we will call you `auto_ptr`)

Answer (score 1):

It is **your** responsibility to equip your class with a copy constructor such that the expression `Foo x(y);` results in an object `x` that is *semantically equal to `y`*. Nobody forces you to do that in any particular way, and the program will behave as *you* tell it to.

Consider this simplified example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int value;
    explicit Foo(int n) : value(n) { }
    Foo(Foo const & rhs) : value(rhs.n / 5 - 32) { } // tee-hee
};

Foo make_it_so() { return Foo(40); }

int main() { Foo k = make_it_so(); }
```

Now depending on whether the copy constructor is elided or not, `k.value` ends up either with `40` or with `-24`. However, because *you* wrote the copy constructor, you have essentially declared that you consider the two semantically equal.

C++ lets *you* set the rules of the game, but it doesn't protect you from going straight to jail.

(I know that my example is slightly different from what you asked in your question ("argument passing"), but it is intended to illustrate your responsibilities as an author.)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious happens. The object is copied. The values are set to whatever you do in the copy constructor. You can confirm this by simply printing the values.

Copy-elision is not allowed here as the argument passed into the function is not an rvalue. If it were an rvalue (e.g. `func(C())`) the code would not compile as the temporary cannot be bound to the copy constructor as it is taking a reference as argument and not a reference to const. If this is fixed, copy-elision can be observed for the argument and the return value. So the state of `c` after being assigned to *could* be the one of a default constructed `C`.

As far as I understand the code as shown will always show the same behavior and does not depend on optimizations.

Comment: @MarkRansom The behavior of the program still has to be the same even if the copy is elided and thus the values set in the copy constructor have to be in the object the function uses as well.

Comment: I would have thought so too but evidently there are exceptions built into the standard. From the Wikipedia link: "The standard also describes a few situations where copying can be eliminated even if this would alter the program's behavior, the most common being the return value optimization."

Comment: @MarkRansom Exactly. But there is no return value here. The difference between those optimizations is not so subtle. RVO becomes an obvious optimization as soon as a function is inlined, while passing an argument by value does not as this would require full analysis of the side-effects of the functions called on that value because otherwise you would change the original value that was passed in.

Comment: @pmr : Copy-elision is a different optimization than RVO, and _does_ apply to arguments passed by value (and consequently _is_ pertinent to this question).

Comment: A temporary *must* be constructed from `func(c)` to assign to `c`. That temporary is to be constructed as a copy of `c`, so one of the two copies (to the argument or to the return value) can't be elided.

Comment: @ildjarn But the exception that copy-elision cannot be performed on lvalue is exactly the case here. The optimization here is simply not possible. If there were a copy ctor taking a `const&` AND if the argument would actually be an rvalue it would. But you are right, the answer is not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a copy constructor with the same signature as the default copy constructor, you are suppressing the default one from being created.

So when the code calls for the default copy constructor it will run the one you have made and do whatever you put in there, be it printing, memory allocation, or even just do nothing if that is how you coded it.

Comment: "*When you write a copy constructor with the same signature as the default copy constructor, you are overloading the default one that exists.*" No, you're _suppressing_ the default one from being generated in the first place.